# Cannot convert from object to string error

Tags: model-view-controller, stored-procedures

Hi I have code like this :

```
foreach (DataRow dr in upCSV.Rows)
                    {
ObjectParameter getCustomField1 = new ObjectParameter("CustomField1", String.IsNullOrEmpty(dr["CustomField1"]) ? null : Convert.ToInt32(dr["CustomField1"]));

var results = ordertable.usp_AppUpdateUserData(Convert.ToInt32( getCustomField1) )
   }
```

Here I am getting error as **Cannot convert from object to string** .

Here Customefield1 is of int type and it has null value. So when i debug, it is showing value for customfield1 as  **" "**. So how can I convert this to int and pass it to my Stored procedure ?

Comment: There is no conversion from empty string to number. Is empty string 0 or 3 or 42?

Answer (score 0):

You can cast your `dr["CustomField1"]` object directly to an `int?`:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in upCSV.Rows)
```

{

int? CustomField1 = dr["CustomField1"] as int?;

ObjectParameter getCustomField1 ;

```
if (CustomField1.HasValue)
{
    getCustomField1 = new ObjectParameter("CustomField1", CustomField1);
}
else
{
    getCustomField1 = new ObjectParameter("CustomField1", typeof(global::System.Int32));
    getCustomField1.Value = DBNull.Value;
}
    var results = ordertable.usp_AppUpdateUserData(getCustomField1);
```

}

Comment: Hi if i do as you said, I am getting value cannot be null error